# How to find out if the sample size determines the observed pattern?

Tags: regression, sample-size

I have a database (annual frequency) that gets periodically updated.

As a result, every point in time (year) has a different number of observations: each version, adds a new data point to every time point. This means that earlier observations have more data points than later observations. Also, the number of available data points falls as time aproaches the present.

For the particular variable I'm interested in, I notice that as time advances, the mean tends to fall short of the median (the mean and the median are the statistics calculated at every time point, across available dataset versions).

I suspect that the relative difference I observe between the mean and the median (positive in the earlier period of the dataset and negative for more recent time points) might be an artifact of the declining sample size.

Are there any tests in the literature I could employ to make sense of what's going on?

My intuition is to run a linear regression on the difference between the mean and the median, on sample size, with dummies for the slope and intercept and check if they are significantly different between different periods.

However I'm not sure how to pin down the exact date to use as a breakpoint.

Also, the number of observations at each point in time are not that many and get less as time approaches the present, making me question what exactly am I calculating what I take eg. the mean and the median of two or three data points.

Comment: Testing presupposes you have independent random samples.  In such cases there shouldn't be detectable amounts of variation between mean and median as a function of sample size unless you are using some strange biased estimators of one or both of them.  Instead of formal testing, consider graphical exploration of the changes as the series is updated, with a focus on the mechanisms whereby data are selected for updates.

Comment: Could there be a bias a for the very small sample sizes in question, when the underlying distribution from which sample means/medians are calculated is asymmetric? I simulated three cases: a) sampling 3 values from a 1 d.o.f. chi-square distribution; b) 17 values from the same; and c) 101 values from the same, in each case calculating the "mean - median" metric. There's a significant difference between the sample means of the a) and b) datasets, though less so between those of the b) and of c) datasets.

Comment: @whuber thank you, I really appreciate the input; is it possible to elaborate on "with a focus on the mechanisms whereby data are selected for updates" because I don't understand what it means; the data are updated at semi-regular intervals (used to be every four months, now its biannually) by the institution that is assigned with this task

Comment: @jwimberley I really have no clue what the underlying distribution is; it could be symmetric, asymmetric or anything in between. The data points are really scarce to make any sense out of them (as little as 5 or less for more recent time points)

Comment: I'd second whuber's good advice to look at graphical methods here -- you have so few data points that many statistics would be unreliable, in particular your "mean minus median" metric (and my impression is that's not a metric with any real significance that you need to measure, but just a pattern you're curious about)